# How do I search for a specific value in a 2d array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I want to iterate through 2 specific rows of a 2d array to find a specific value, but I am unable to do so.

In my program, I have read in a 2d array from a text file using the following code:

```
with open ("maze_10x10.txt") as maze:
    for line in maze:
        row = [item.strip() for item in line.split(' ')]
        a.append(row)
```

For reference, the text file looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to find the coordinate of the only zeroes in the first and last rows of the array and I am attempting to do this with this code:

```
start = 9,0
end = 0,0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[9][i] == 0:
        start = 9,i
print(start)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[0][i] == 0:
        end = 0,i
print(end)
```

But the start and end variables remain unchanged when I run it.

Comment: `0 != "0"`. You need to either convert everything to an integer, or compare each element to the _string_ `"0"`. Also you loop over _all_ rows of `a` to check only the first and last rows. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to start from scratch.

Once you load the file into `a`, a is:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', ''],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', ''],
 ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', ''],
 ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '']]
```

First thing you want to do is filter out the empty strings (`''`) and turn the non-empty strings into `int`s. This can be achieved with a nested list comprehension.

```
a = [[int(number) for number in row if number != ''] for row in a]
```

Then, `a` looks something like:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Then, you can define a function to scan a row from a list, returning the coordinates of each match.

```
def scan(lst, row_number, match):
    row = lst[row_number]
    matches = []
    for i, element in enumerate(row):
        if element == match:
            matches.append((row_number, i))
    return matches
```

Then, you can try running it for the first row:

```
print(scan(a, 0, 0))  # Outputs [(0, 7)]
```

And the last row:

```
print(scan(a, 9, 0))  # Outputs [(9, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with your if statement. You are reading a text file and comparing it to an integer. Try either adding quotes to the zeros or converting each number to an integer

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[9][i] == "0":
        start = 9,i
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the first and last rows, you don't need to loop over all the row indexes.

And you can use the built-in `index()` method to find the position of the `0` in a specific row.

```
start = (9, a[9].index(0))
end = (0, a[0].index(0))
```